# How can I add custom column types to a wpf datagrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls

I currently have a bound datagrid which is autogenerating columns

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding TestRows}"
                      HeadersVisibility="All"
                      GridLinesVisibility="Vertical" 
                      BorderBrush="Gray" 
                      BorderThickness="5"
                      IsReadOnly="False"
                      CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                      CanUserSortColumns = "True"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                      SelectionMode="Single"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                      AutoGeneratingColumn="dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn">
...
...
...
</DataGrid>
```

The auto generation works great for strings and ints, but I also have an object of type `Dictionary<String, Strategy>` on the items in my data collection. The Dictionary has the same key for every item in `TestRows`, but the content differs.

What I want is for the datagrid to dynamically add a custom `DataGridTemplateColumn` for each key in the Dictionary, using a specific property from the value as the cell value. I suspect that I could add something for this into `dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn` but I can't find a way to do so.

How could I go about achieving what I described above?

Comment: For each key in what dictionary? There is only one column for all rows but you have a dictionary property per row, haven't you? So which dictionary are you referring to?

Comment: TestRows is a ObservableCollection of objects, with one row per object in the collection. The data grid automatically generates a column for every string and int in the object, which is what I want. However, I also have a dictionary in the object. The dictionary has the same keys in every object in TestRows, but I don't know what those keys will be until runtime. I want to dynamically generate columns based on this dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

> TestRows is a ObservableCollection of objects, with one row per object in the collection. The data grid automatically generates a column for every string and int in the object, which is what I want. However, I also have a dictionary in the object. The dictionary has the same keys in every object in TestRows, but I don't know what those keys will be until runtime.

The `AutoGeneratingColumn` is raised after the `ItemsSource` has been set so you could handle the `AutoGeneratingColumn` something like this:

```
private void dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(YourClass.YourDictionaryPropertyName))
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        DataGrid dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
        IList sourceCollection = dataGrid.ItemsSource as IList;
        MyClass firstItem = sourceCollection?[0] as MyClass;
        foreach (var key in firstItem.YourDictionaryPropertyName.Keys)
        {
            dataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Header = "...", Binding = new Binding($"{nameof(YourClass.YourDictionaryPropertyName)}"[{key}]") });
        }
    }
}
```

...where `YourClass` is an item in "TestRows":

```
public class YourClass
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> YourDictionaryPropertyName { get; }
    ...
}
```